# Determine if a parametrization is bijective.

Tags: differential-geometry

In the image below, I've highlighted what is also my question. The author says it is "easy to check, that it is a bijection from $U$ to $G$". I mean, is'nt this trivial? Is there really something to check ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is fairly trivial, but you can get some nice explanation if you do check.  Notice that the definition of $G$ is *precisely* the same as the definition of the image $x[U]$ - so of course they are equal which implies surjectivity. Naturally, since there is the projection $\pi:R^3\rightarrow R^2,\,\,\,(u,v,z)\mapsto (u,v)$ and $\pi\circ x$ is the identity, which is injective, it follows that $x$ is injective.